# How to locally install django third-party apps?

Tags: django, django-apps

I'm making a small django project where I use third-party apps like South and others. I will probably rent a host to this project, so I won't be able to install these apps via easy_install. Is there a way to install these apps inside my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/) is great for this, especially when combined with [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/).

```
$ virtualenv myproject
$ cd myproject/
$ . bin/activate
(myproject) $ pip install django
(myproject) $ pip install south
```

Comment: But is it possible to use virtualenv in a rented host? I don't think I will have access to a command line, I'll only be abe to use it through FTP.

Comment: FTP-only hosters are not really suited for running a Django app. How do you want to run all the managment command that Django and South use? e.g. `syncdb`, `migrate`...

Comment: Oh, I get it. I did some search, there are some hosting sites that offer SSH, maybe they allow the use of easy_install or pip. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcio try Webfaction, highly recommended for hosting Django sites.

Answer (score 3):

For example: `django-grappelli`. Install python setup tools and do the next step

```
$ pip install django-grappelli
```

and then add to the installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

This is the way for your question